# How to Regexextract whole words that contain a mixture of text and numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make this formula work for a mixture of text and numbers. It works for text that contain 4 numbers only. How can I manipule this to match specific words e.g `Text Text 50` or even `random 2020 text`.

I need to hardcode the words into the formula or using INDIRECT cell reference.

The formula I got.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,TRIM(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"^([øa-zA-Z-\/ ]+)"))&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A," [0-9]{4}")))))
```

I simpler terms I want the formula to extract these specific words as they are without trimming them. This formula works for other strings except ones that are a mixture of numbers and text.

I tried to edit my formula like this but I wasn't successful.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,TRIM(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"^([[:Text Text 50:]][[:random 2020 text:]][øa-zA-Z-\/ ]+)"))&IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A," [0-9]{4}")))))
```

The link to my spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BYW-QzqRA8vIBWazDSZhbUZ_TCbVAPYSI-1hFthfrew/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add what you want the results to look like please?

Comment: Just as you use \d to specify 0-9 digits, I need to specify a specific word once found should be returned as is. E.g from my example above, the formula should return ```Text Text 50``` and ```random 2020 text``` as is once found. So it's like using a whole word as a delimeter if that makes sense.

Comment: This formula ```=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR({REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"AC Text 1921"),REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"B93 Random"),REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"Other 1345 text..")})) ``` seems to work except that it's throwing the results in the subsequent cells instead of the cell that has the formula. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter the texts you are looking for in a separate column (say into `E1:E3`), you can use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,JOIN("|",E1:E3))),"")
```

[image]

If you want hardcode, just use:

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"AC Reggiana 1919|B93 Copenhagen|Etar 1924 Veliko T..")),"")
```